# How can I directly use the selected value of a select element in on:change?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I know I can bind the value to a local variable, say `selectedItem`, and then use this variable in `on:change` like this:

```
<select bind:value={selectedItem} on:change={() => doSomething(selectedItem)}>
```

But in some cases, I would prefer to directly use `value` in `on:change()`, without having to define an intermediate `selectedItem` variable first. However, I can't find a way to do this, what am I missing?

EDIT:

I should have mentionend, that the items int the list are *objects*, and therefore using event.target.value won't work. My question seems to boil down to: Why can `value` be used for binding, but cannot somehow be used in `on:change`?

Comment: take a look of this example `https://svelte.dev/repl/3b540047caa44fc6b0e0c7ad5c23e3f7?version=3.46.4`

Comment: @MohitSharma Thanks, but your example is binding to a local variable, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid...

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the value via `on:change={(event) => doSth(event.target.value)}`
will give the value as string. While this is basically no problem with primitives, the advantage with the value binding is that Svelte preserves the original type and you can use objects as values. These can't be accessed via `event.target.value` though - this will give only `[object Object]`

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/aa0cee64fd674ef6a8c456c869fd4db6?version=3.50.1)

```
<script>
    const options = [1,2,3]
    let selectedOption = ''

    let questions = [
        { id: 1, text: `Where did you go to school?` },
        { id: 2, text: `What is your mother's name?` },
        { id: 3, text: `What is another personal fact that an attacker could easily find with Google?` }
    ];
    let selectedQuestion = ''
</script>

<select bind:value={selectedOption}
        on:change={(event) => console.log(event.target.value, typeof event.target.value, selectedOption, typeof selectedOption)}
    >
    {#each options as option}
    <option value={option}>
        {option}
    </option>
    {/each}
</select>

<select bind:value={selectedQuestion}
        on:change={(event) => console.log(event.target.value, selectedQuestion)}
    >
    {#each questions as question}
    <option value={question}>
        {question.text}
    </option>
    {/each}
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Corrl, so you're basically saying what I hope to do is simply not possible? i.e. in case the selection option is an object, there's no way around value binding to a local variable? This seems surpising to me and - if true - a rare occasion where I feel Svelte could make it simpler/better.

Comment: @virt Svelte adds functionality so it's possbile to bind different types and objects to a variable, but it doesn't change what's given https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties#:~:text=HTML%20attributes%20have%20the%20following,Their%20values%20are%20always%20strings. To avoid various varibles and group stuff it's also possible to bind to object values `bind:value={values.selectedOption}` or array indexes. If you absolutely want to avoid the binding and have an object value you could stringify/parse - I added that to the Repl.

Comment: The JSON.parse is interesting, thanks. I guess I just struggle with the fact that Svelte allows to bind `value` to a local variable, but cannot make the same `value` available (as object) in `on:change` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onChange parameter to find the target's value:

```html
<select on:change={(e) => doSomething(e.target.value)}>
```

You may read more about the docs here: [HTMLElement change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

Comment: As Corrl's answer points out, this only gives the value as string. I guess I should have pointed out that in my case, the selected option is a an object, so I only get [object Object].

Comment: I see. Ideally you'd use bind for this, but you can for example use JSON.stringify on each value of the options in the select. Then in the onChange function, you can do JSON.parse(e.target.value). This would solve the [object object] issue. However, it feels hacky.